# What am I missing in jsFiddle for AngularJS example

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I am trying to run some AngularJS code in jsFiddle but nothing is showing. I must be missing something:

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="Controller">
            <my-customer></my-customer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.customer = {
        name: 'Naomi',
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
    };
}])
    .directive('myCustomer', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AndroidDev/Wd72j/5/

EDIT:

I came across this example which does show AngularJS working:
http://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/

But what I don't understand is why there is an additional version of AngularJS listed in the dropdown list whereas in mine it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you haven't take a look into console output
you had a `templateUrl` but no file was attached so it simply couldn't be loaded

http://jsfiddle.net/Wd72j/6/

Comment: I copied that code straight from angularjs.org website not realizing that the templateUrl was invalid. I also discovered that you also need to use the "no wrap - in <head>" option, otherwise AngularJS will not work at all.